# getchar() stuck in a loop never reaching the EOF

Tags: c, scanf, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    while(getchar() != EOF) {
        if (getchar() == ' ') {
            c++;
        }
        printf("%i", c);
    }
}
```

I realized that typing in a sentence like the one you're reading right

I\nrealized\nthat\ntyping\nin\n\a\n ...

i believe that's how it's being read, getchar() does not reach the EOF to make the condition in the while parentheses false..

my goal here is to make a program that takes in input from me..
reads it
if there are any spaces 
it counts on a counter
when EOF is reached
the condition to keep reading it becomes false
the counter value gets printed out on the screen
to show me how many spaces i had in my entire input..

is it impossible? is that why people just use scanf() ?

this is the output i get when trying something

```
user@user:/c# ./a.out
hello stackoverflow this does not do what i want it to
001111111222223344445666677
```

Comment: You realize `c` doesn't have a defined value, right? And not everyone uses `scanf`. It often isn't the best solution for reading input from the user.

Comment: In a linux terminal, `CTRL-d`, I believe, should send in an end of file.

Comment: An on certain Windows environments, a <kbd>CTRL-z</kbd>.

Comment: Why are you reading with `getchar` twice? You never set `c`. `while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {...}` or something like that, as you don't take any notice of what is read.

Comment: help me by explaining stuff to me, instead of telling me i'm wrong and i need to go check my code..

Comment: Thus far, nobody has said "you're wrong, go check your code".

Comment: it really sounds like it would work, but still, my original question remains.. when does the EOF int get stored into the variable ch.. it doesn't. the text string is a bunch of consecutive letters and new line characters, the loop goes on and on, getchar() never stops "getting chars" and the EOF is never met..

Comment: It will *never* get stored in a variable, because you never store it in one. If you want to save the result of getchar() (or any function) you need to assign it with c = getchar() or equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the result of `getchar()` into a variable:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
```

You shouldn't call `getchar()` a second time to check if it's a space, since that will read a second character so you'll be testing every other character, just compare the variable:

```
    if (ch == ' ')
```

And if you want to see the total number of spaces, put the `printf()` at the end of the loop, not inside it.

So the whole thing should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int counter=0;
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", counter);
}
```

To send `EOF` from the terminal, type <kbd>Control-d</kbd> on Unix, <kbd>Control-z</kbd> on Windows.

Comment: it really sounds like it would work, but still, my original question remains..

when does the EOF int get stored into the variable ch..

it doesn't. the text string is a bunch of consecutive letters and new line characters, the loop goes on and on, getchar() never stops "getting chars" and the EOF is never met..